# Update values corresponding to different existing keys in unordred_map from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have an unordered map looks like this:

```
unordered_map<string, MyClass*> idToMyClassMap;
```

Now I understand that I cannot do insert/delete and etc to this map from multiple threads without synchronization. But can I pre-populate this map with the largest possible entries that I will use with an list of pre-known string key and all nullptr for MyClass. When I actually want to "insert" to this map, I will just iterate through the map, find which key is nullptr and use that. When I am deleting, I will set the value to nullptr again.

Would this work?

Comment: You mean like `unordered_map<string, MyClass*> idToMyClassMap{{"foo", nullptr},{"bar", nullptr}};`?

Comment: I would make it properly synchronized first and measure if it really needs that hacks (which are dangerous).

Comment: @Slava, those are not hacks, but very standard practice.

Comment: @SergeyA when you deduce what method can do and cannot do from observed behavior, but not from documentation I would consider that as a hack.

Comment: @Slava, which methods are you referring to?

Comment: @SergeyA non const version of `std::unordered_map::find()`

Comment: @Slava, it is your choice to infer gurantees from behavior, not documentation, not mine. Have you chosen to infer it from documentation, like I did, you'd find this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container and read it.

Comment: @Then you should point to this documentation and put a quote from it.

Comment: @Slava, if you are not familiar with certain area, you should ask the question, rather than assuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would work in the sense that you will not be subjecting yourself to race conditions - assuming you do not modify the same element from more than one thread.

`find` is a rare example of the container member function which is not marked `const` (because it returns modifiable iterator) but still is safe to be called from multiple threads simultaneously.

To get more information on container thread-safety, I strongly recommend memorizing this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container